# How to recognize doubles and negative vaules

Tags: java

// The program compiles and runs as it should to compute averages I am just struggling to add negative, and double values to it.

```
import java.util.*;
    public class DoWhileLoops {
        public static void main (String [] args) {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            int sum = 0,
            ct = 0;
            String input = "";
            do {
                System.out.println
                ("Enter a positive whole number, or q to quit.");
                int n=0, sct=0;
                char c;
                input = kb.nextLine();
                do {
                    c = input.charAt(sct);
                    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                    {
                        n = n * 10;
                        n += (int)(c - '0');
                    }
                    sct++;
                } while (sct < input.length());
                if (n > 0) {
                    sum += n;
                    ct++;
                }
            } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
            System.out.printf("The sum of the %d numbers you entered is: %d\n", ct, sum);
            if(ct > 0)
                System.out.printf("The average is: %.2f", (double)sum/ct);
            else
                System.out.printf("No numbers entered - can't compute average");
        }
    }
```

//Need help having the program so it will recognize positive and negative values as well as doubles.

Comment: Why not just take the input and store it in a double?

Comment: By using Scanner object, you can type double, int, String, negative number...

Comment: why you are not using default methods like: `kb.nextDouble()` or `kb.nextInt()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You use a [Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) within a [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method to determine if the User has entered a string representation of a valid number of either a signed (negative) or unsigned (positive) integer or double data type value, for example:

```
if (!input.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
    System.err.println("Invalid numerical value supplied! Try again..." + ls);
    continue;
}
```

The regular expression used in the **matches()** method above is: `"-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` and here is an explanation of what it means:

[image]

When summing, you want to use a double data type variable which means then that when the User supplies a value we want to parse it to a double data type. To do this you can use the [Double.parseDouble()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm) method to convert the string numerical value to a double data type and add that value to our summation (the **sum** variable which we've already declared as ***double***).

Here is what the code might look like:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
double sum = 0;
int counter = 0;
String input;
do {
    System.out.print((counter + 1) + ") Enter a numerical value (or q to finish): ");
    input = kb.nextLine();
    // If the first character supplied by User is a Q then exit loop
    if (Character.toString(input.charAt(0)).equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        break;
    }
    // If the value supplied is not a numerical value
    // then inform User and let him/her/it try again.
    if (!input.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid numerical value supplied! Try again..." + ls);
        continue;
    }

    counter++;
    double num = Double.parseDouble(input);
    sum += num;
} while (true);  // q must be given to exit loop.

System.out.printf(ls + "The sum of the %d numbers you entered is: %f\n", counter, sum);
if (counter > 0) {
    System.out.printf("The average is: %.2f", (double) sum / counter);
}
else {
    System.out.printf("No numerical values entered! - Can not compute average!");
}
```